# IP Accounting to SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, networking, mikrotik

I need help compiling a php script that will fetch IP accounting data from my MikroTik router and store it into a sql database,

On MikroTik the IP accounting is displayed on the web port in cgi eg. http://routerip:webport/accounting/ip.cgi

After every request to ip.cgi the router automatically clears all data.

On ip.cgi the data is displayed:

196.10.52.57 192.168.1.60 456 6 * *
157.240.1.32 192.168.2.16 612 6 * *
192.168.1.23 38.90.226.38 2124 15 * *
23.21.244.249 192.168.1.23 6219 13 * * 
157.240.1.18 192.168.1.23 9881 27 * *
192.168.1.23 23.21.244.249 1987 20 * *

The first ip is the src address, second ip is the dst address, the next number is the bytes transferred and the last number is the packets transferred. The stars are not needed, I don't even know what they are for.

I have this code so far to connect to the database but cannot figure out how to pull the info from the ip.cgi page ans store it into the database

```
<?php

$SQLserver = "localhost";
$SQLusername = "root";
$SQLpassword = "sqlpassword";
$SQLdatabase = "sqldatabase";



$RouterIP = "192.168.1.1";
$WebPort = "81";
$AccountingLocation = "accounting/ip.cgi";

$routerconnect = "http://$RouterIP:$WebPort/$AccountingLocation";

$orig = file_get_contents($routerconnect);
$a = htmlentities($orig);

$conn = mysqli_connect($SQLserver, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, 
$SQLdatabase);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounting (src_address, dst_address, bytes, packets)
VALUES ('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3', '4')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I will be adding this php script to a cron job to run every 5 minutes to store accounting data for my OSPF network, all accounting is done on my core mikrotik router.

Comment: It looks like you'll be successfully pulling the info from the router with your `file_get_contents()` call. Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I got that part right but the part that I am wanting to do is to store the information into the sql database correctly, I am still teaching myself php language, I know very little of it so far. I need to store the source IP, destination IP, bytes and packets into my mysql database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've pulled the data with `file_get_contents()` into your `$orig` variable, you'll need to parse it out:

```
foreach ( explode( "\n", $orig ) as $line ) {
    if ( trim( $line )) {
        list( $src, $dst, $bytes, $packets ) = explode( ' ', trim( strip_tags( $line )));

        // Now $src, $dst, $bytes, and $packets contain your data
        $sql = "INSERT INTO accounting (src_address, dst_address, bytes, packets) VALUES ('$src', '$dst', '$bytes', '$packets')";

        // Then the rest of your code to execute the query goes here
    }
}
```

This will break the result into individual lines, then break the lines into pieces (assuming that the pieces are separated by spaces as it appears they are in your question).  From there, you can handle the SQL part that you've already written.

Check into the documentation for [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) for more information about what's happening there.

Comment: Okay I have tried that, I am now getting:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/learnphp/test.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/learnphp/test.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/learnphp/test.php on line 25

on line 25 I have:
    list( $src, $dst, $bytes, $packets ) = explode( ' ', $line );

Comment: The code I used was dependent on `$orig` containing the data in the style you posted in your question. Most likely, it's being output in a slightly different format (for instance, one or more blank lines above or below the output). So you'll need to modify it to detect any deviations like that.

Comment: If I open ip.cgi from my router using a web browser it shows exactly like I posted but when I echo or print the file_get_contents and I view that php in the browser it all shows as one long line

Comment: If you look at the browser source, what does it look like? Is it possible there's HTML code there that's formatting it a certain way (which wouldn't show in the browser, but only when viewing the source)?

Comment: If I inspect element on the ip.cgi from the router, it displays:


<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">192.168.1.23 172.16.12.235 180 3 * *
192.168.3.2 192.168.1.23 578133 481 * *
192.168.1.23 192.168.3.2 8760 219 * *
172.16.12.235 192.168.1.23 180 3 * *
</pre></body></html>

Comment: Ah, yes, so there's lots of other stuff there besides the data you're looking for. Doing an Inspect Element in your browser isn't the same as viewing the source (the former will show you the code after the browser has formatted, sometimes even adding or removing HTML code, but the latter will show you literally what the web server sent to your browser). I've updated my answer to hopefully account for this. But without knowing what the source literally is, I can't know for sure, so you'll need to test again.

Comment: Alright, I have updated the code but I am still getting the same error, 


Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/learnphp/test.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/learnphp/test.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/learnphp/test.php on line 25

Comment: Could it not be a problem with the two stars that are printed out aswell?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with the stars, those are just extra parameters we're ignoring. The notice is saying that the parameters we're looking for aren't there, so it's opposite of having too many parameters. Until I can see the actual source, I can't say for sure what the issue is.

Comment: How can I get the source of my routers ip.cgi?
If you're able to, you can download a x86 iso from mikrotik.com and install is on a virtual machine and have a look at IP>Accounting in the configuration.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, once you visit the page in your browser, use your browser's View Source function. This is not the same as using the Inspect Element function.

Comment: If I view source code, it shows exactly like I had it in my question

Comment: [MikroTik accounting.ip.cgi source code][1]

[If I echo $orig in PHP, I get this][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUBLN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krStx.png

Comment: My guess would be that there's some errant whitespace at the end of the return. I've modified the code to include a conditional to ignore that.

Comment: Thank you!! That worked :) Now I need help with another script, I have asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781582/transfer-ip-accounting-to-single-row-table

Comment: How can I modify the code to check my variables in my config file, I will add one $InternalIpAddresses = "192.168.0.0/16,172.16.1.1/24" separated by commas and with subnet cidr notations to then pull the information from the router like I did but instead of adding all the values with src and dst, rather add all the bytes from the src addresses that are in my variable $InternalIpAddresses and add all the bytes together instead of individual rows in sql and then the same for dst addresses, so src will be download and dst will be upload traffic?

Something like in the next comment:

Comment: 192.168.x.x 0.0.0.0 2046 and 0.0.0.0 192.168.x.x 1024, where 2046 will be downloaded traffic and 1024 will be uploaded traffic

Comment: If my answer was helpful or correct, you may want to upvote or accept it. If you have another question about your code (like the one you posted in your comment above), you should post it as a separate question rather than as a comment to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, can you have a look at this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781582/transfer-ip-accounting-to-single-row-table